# Data on screen updated when database changed on realtime database firebase using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Can u update the value of data on your screen base on the data in the firebase real time database without refreshing the screen.

I have a sensor that send value each 10 second and when the database updated using that value. The value on my app screen still showing the last data and wont change unless you leave that screen or refresh it manually.

can it be done automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely. Firebase is very good at that. You can setup realtime listeners to the value you are displaying. Both databases support it. I don't see what database you use but if you provide me that info I could share with you some example code.

The best way in Flutter would be to use a `StreamBuilder`. You can find more information about it [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview).

Comment: after reading from the link that you shared it is firestore correct? currently im using the real time database one and i dont know what should i do with that information that u give to me. im really sorry im still learning and my english is not that goos. Hope you can respond

Comment: Did you install the firebase packages to your Flutter project liek `firebase-core`? Here are some instructions for the basic setup: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview

Comment: When you open your project in firebase. theres menu on the left right? authentication, firestore then real time database. so they can interact with each other? i thought they work separately

Comment: All that can work together but not directly. You would need to write code or cloud functions to make them share data. But in the background auth is linked to the databases and you define with the database rules who can see or edit what.